# Possible to speed up this PyMongo/MongoDB bulk operation loop?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a Python function that uses PyMongo to process a large set of JSON data (tens of thousands of measurements/timestamps), then constructs a MongoDB bulk write operation (using PyMongo). While this code works, it is *extremely* slow, and seems to get slower the longer it runs. Any advice regarding how this could be optimized would be greatly appreciated!

```
def import_metrics(user, data):

    i = 0
    bulkop = db.metrics.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()

    # data is a JSON object containing tens of thousands of measurements:
    # data[metrics] = [
    #   {
    #     value: int
    #     ts   : timestamp
    #   },
    # ]
    for entry in data['metrics']

        utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(entry['ts'])

        # ignore if entry is null
        if isinstance(entry['value'], float):
            # upsert data
            metric = {
                'userId':    ObjectId(user['_id']),
                'ts':        utc_dt
                'value':     int(entry['value']),
            }
            key = {
                'userId':   ObjectId(user['_id']),
                'ts':       utc_dt
            }

            # add query to bulk operation
            bulkop.find(key).upsert().update_one({'$set': metric})

            i = i + 1

    if i > 0:
        # we have some data to insert
        try:
            result = bulkop.execute()
        except BulkWriteError as bwe:
            print 'ERROR: ' + str(bwe.details)
```

Note that there is just 1 index on the collection:

```
> db.metrics.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "mydb.metrics"
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check for i=1000 and execute bulk operation and restart counter

Comment: Index on db.metrics collection for userId and ts would help a lot and I think this why you have speed decreasing during execution, because number of docs is increasing and upsert doing full scan longer.